# vue.js Failed to mount component: template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, gulp

i am working hard to solve this issue but not found any one please help me about this
here is my code
calling component

```
Vue.component('select2', require('./components/select2.vue'));
```

html of component

```
<template>
    <select>
        <slot></slot>
    </select>
</template>
```

here is my vue.js script

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['options', 'value', 'params'],
        mounted: function () {
            var vm = this;
            var params = !this.params ? {} : this.params;
            params.val = this.value;
            if(this.options) {
                params.data = this.options;
            }
            $(this.$el).val(this.value);
            $(this.$el).select2(params);
            $(this.$el).on('change', function () {
                vm.$emit('input', $(this).val()) 
            })
            $(this.$el).val(this.value).trigger('change');
        },
        watch: {
            value: function (value) {
                $(this.$el).val(value);
            },
            options: function (options) {
                var params = !this.params ? {} : this.params;
                if(this.options) {
                    params.data = this.options;
                }
                $(this.$el).select2(params);
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
        }
    }
</script>
```

but still getting this error i tried alot of things but not working please help me i can give you more detials if you needed i am using laravel ,gulp etc

[image]

Comment: What you posted should work, there's something else that's breaking. You'll need to dig deeper and provide more details. Are you sure the <ListAdvance> component is working?

Comment: Please, add code that shows usage of `select2` component. Also, try wrapping `<select>` tag with a `<div>`, in case `select2` plugin replaces DOM element, it may cause issues for Vue render.

Comment: can that issue releated to gulp -development command laravel or some configuration issue

Comment: ListAdvance component is not working

Comment: i can show you my code on skype and i can pay you good amout for help too

Comment: By the way you wrote, it looks like you separated the template and the script.
Are they both defined in the same file?

Comment: yes there are defined in same file